# Excel: Transpose stacked data in one column to multiple rows based on a consistent cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to transpose a single column into multiple rows. The row break should be based on the row following a cell containing "Contact buyer".  Below is an example of the data:

jeneice07 on 13 May, 2019

5 out of 5 stars

Report this review

Contact buyer

Tree of Life Stone Necklace Wire Wrapped Crystal Pendant Stone Womens Jewellery Nature Jewelry Gifts for Her Green Gem Copper Tree Design

The number of rows in each review is variable or this would be a simple problem to solve. I need code that will look for "Contact buyer" then go one additional cell and transpose that then transpose the next review another row down.  I can change the cells containing contact buyer to any value that may be required to make this easier than it being a string.

I searched heavily for any solution to this issue. I have over 100000 rows of data so doing this manually isn't an option. I tried modifying the code below but it doesn't work because I cannot get the stepVal to be variable.

```
Public Sub TransposePaste()
   'Value we want to step by....
    Dim stepVal As Long
    stepVal = "
'Declare start row variable (-1)
 Dim row As Long
 row = 0

'Declare the column the data is coming from
Dim col As Long
col = 1

'Declare and set worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1

'end row of the data
Dim endRow As Long 
endRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row

'cycle to end of data end of data...
For i = 1 To endRow Step stepVal

'increment row each time
row = row + 1

    'cycle through the columns outputting the data
    For j = 1 To stepVal

    Sheet1.Cells(row, j).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + j - 1, col).Value

    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

[image: Input data looks like this. It is 10K rows of user comments]

Output example below taken from first two entries of the input data and I added one additional item where the reviewer added a photo which results in the review being seven cells long instead of five:

[image: Output Example]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of data please - your example doesn't really help?

Comment: @Greg Why is `stepVal = "`? This is declared as `Long` which means you can assign only numbers to it.

Comment: You need to post better example of your input data and desired output.

Comment: your second image doesn't match with your verbal process description (for output = determining next row) as there is more than one column after the contact buyer in the second row (crystal....)

Comment: @QHarr you are correct. Sorry that is my mistake please ignore the input in row "F" I am scrubbing those.  All of them only have one cell worth of useful data after "contact buyer"

Answer (score 0):

Disregard. I am just going to manually scrub the data to get the length to be a consistent 5 rows then use the code above.